# How do I use split-window-sensibly with ediff-setup-windows-plain together?

Tags: window, ediff

I want `ediff` to use `split-window-sensibly` so it will stack the diffs on top/bottom when the window is narrow, but side-by-side when the window is wide. I'd like to use a single frame instead of the overlay help window (`ediff-setup-windows-plain`).

So I set these two settings in my .emacs:

```el
(setq ediff-split-window-function 'split-window-sensibly)
(setq ediff-window-setup-function 'ediff-setup-windows-plain)
```

and `M-x vc-ediff` in a git-controlled and modified file.

Then `ediff` fails to display the top window. Only the help buffer and buffer `B` are displayed (with diff highlighting and `ediff` keybindings). As far as I can tell, all I can do to fix this is to use `ediff-setup-windows-multiframe` instead.

I'm using Emacs 24 on Ubuntu (I'm also using spacemacs, but I reproduced without my `.emacs.d`)

Any idea what I can do? I'm not even sure where I'd report a bug (emacs bug, ediff bug, already fixed bug?).

Comment: If there's a behavior you don't find right when running your elisp code in a stock emacs session (`emacs -Q`) (without your .emacs (`~/.emacs.d/init.el` preferred instead)), you can always do `M-x report-emacs-bug`. You will learn from follow up emails if that actually is a bug or if you need to do something different to get what you want.

Comment: I can confirm that I can see the behavior you describe in an `emacs -Q` session. The window splitting works fine if `ediff-split-window-function` is set to `'split-window-horizontally` or `'split-window-vertically`; but not when set to `'split-window-sensibly`. To be specific, the failure to split windows happens only when `split-window-sensibly` tries to split windows **vertically**, not when horizontally. To test this out, make your window/frame wide and then you should see ediff happening between horizontally split buffers without any issue. (emacs 25.x)